# Packet delivery in TCP protocol

Tags: router

Let us assume that station A of 1 Gbit/s wants to send the packets to station B of 100 Mbit/s. There are three routers with 10 Mbit/s, 1 Gbit/s and 10 Mbit/s respectively. How does the packet delivery take place?

Comment: So the link between Station A and the first router...is it 1Gbps or 10Mbps? Or is there a 10/100/1000 switch in between the two?

Comment: Your question is fairly broad. The number or speed of switches have nothing to do with TCP. If you’re asking about packet switching between networks (assumed because you mention routers) you need to be looking at Eth and IP protocols.

Answer (score 10):

TCP [flow control](http://www.brianstorti.com/tcp-flow-control/) will kick in since the speeds are different.

Another thing that could affect TCP in this situation, based on the link type, is if the 1 Gbit/s router is using jumbo frames, but it's no different than if the routers had different MTUs - either the packets would be dropped or fragmented.

Comment: Your answer is correct  but I wonder if this is a newbie question, where the answer is that the data is routed through each router and is limited to the speed of the slowest router, so maximum throughput would be 10Mbps.

Answer (score 9):

In short, you will get 10 Mbit/s throughput.

Naively, one might think that TCP flow control will kick in as stated by LawrenceC, and this is *generally* the correct answer.

However, in your concrete example, it is not.

The 10 Mbit/s router connected to your 1GbE card will negotiate 10 Mbit/s. The same for the 10 Mbit/s router on the intermediate GbE router and on the B side. End of story.

Thus, the network adapter will only ever send and receive at that rate, never exceeding it. Indeed, from your point of view, the entire network is 10 Mbit/s.

The intermediate GbE router might receive and forward packets at 1 Gbit/s with the rest of the world, but will only do 10 Mbit/s on your particular route.

Let's assume the network topology is *somewhat* more complicated (Internet!), and there is *some* amount of gigabit routers, and one or several 10 Mbit/s routers *somewhere* in between. That case is a bit more interesting.

In this case, your computer A will send packets at 1 Gbit/s, but we know that only 10 Mbit/s can make it through (well, not really, with alternative routes, but let's forget that). How can that work?

In this case, indeed, TCP flow control will kick in. Station B will receive packets with 100 Mbit/s but they only come in sporadically. You will send packets with 1 Gbit/s, but you will have to take a pause regularly. This works on the TCP layer without you knowing.

TCP will send out a few packets as fast as it can (and maintain a "window"), and the network card will put them on the wire as fast as it's capable and allowed to, and then TCP will wait for acknowledgements to come in. If they do come in, all is fine and more stuff can be sent as fast as possible. If the ACKs *do not* come in, there was *either* an error (unlikely) or packets were sent too quickly. Therefore the window size is reduced. Once ACKs come in again, the window is gradually enlarged again. There are different algorithms for that, and they are rather elaborate, but in principle that's it.

Now... routers accept a limited number of packets, and forward them according to their ability to do so, as fast as they can. Eventually, they will however have to drop packets. This is not an error, but a normal condition.

Ironically, the presumably old 10 Mbit/s routers are likely to queue a lot of packets (since once upon a time, the belief was "more is always better", nowadays it is known that the opposite is the case, modern routers have very short queues).

The insight that more is not always better comes from the fact that if a router queues a lot of packets and then forwards them, the sender may assume the packets lost (because no ACKs came in) and resend. Which causes the receiver to receive duplicate packets that it must discard *and* it causes the router to become even more congested, pouring oil into the fire. Therefore, modern routers discard quickly.

Now, in the example of an old 10 Mbit/s router *somewhere* in the middle (and speed not negotiated), it is very likely that you get considerably less than 10 Mbit/s throughput due to this. You get resends and double deliveries. None of that is visible to the application, it's just slower for some weird reason.